# Add image and text to a column in datagrid : GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have to add an icon alongside text to specific columns in table in GWT. I looked at `ImageResourceCell` but that would only display image. Does anyone know how to add both text and image to column in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create you own cell for that. But actuall this link:

http://webcentersuite.blogspot.com/2011/03/custom-gwt-clickable-cell-with-images.html

looks like it is the exact thing you are looking for.... Have you tried it out?

(Hurray to bing if it is :D)